# How do I compare data frames in R?

Tags: r

I have two data frames, dfA (t1) and dfB (t2), with subject IDs and associated variables. I want to compare the two data frames based on subject IDs and retain the subject IDs (and the associated variables) that are common to both data frames.

For the final product I'd like two separate data frames that have identical subject IDs and the associated variables.

My original thought to use merge(data, data12, by.y="subject_IDs"), extract subject IDs that are common, and then use rbind function on both data frames. However, the merge function has duplicate subject IDs in the output.

Any suggestions would be most helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
subjects <- levels(factor(dfA$subject_IDs))[levels(factor(dfA$subject_IDs)) %in% levels(factor(dfB$subject_IDs))]
```

gives you all subjects' IDs that are common in both datasets. Then, can subset the two of them with

```
sub_dfA <- dfA[dfA$subject_IDs %in% subjects,]
sub_dfB <- dfB[dfB$subject_IDs %in% subjects,]
```

Note that I am using `data.frame` notation and not `data.table`'s (the latter much more recommended). If you need to append (`rbind`) the two -- I do not see why -- you could try

```
library(data.table)
data_together <- rbindlist(list(sub_dfA, sub_dfB), fill=T)
```

note that I use `rbindlist` and not `rbind` because you did not specify whether the two datasets have the save variables/columns. I am guessing that `subject_IDs` is the name of the variable that identifies the subjects in each data frame. Try to share (a piece, at least) of your data so that answers can be more precise.